# Domain Driven Design: Herança ou Classes Parciais

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, ddd, polimorfismo, partial

Estou no desenvolvimento de um projeto para finalidade de estudo com a abordagem Domain Driven Design (DDD), para fins do problema considere a seguinte classe:

```
    public abstract class Message: Entity
    {
            protected Message(string messageId, string chatId, string fromId, string receiverId, long timestamp, MessageContent content)
            {
                MessageId = messageId;
                FromId = fromId;
                ReceiverId = receiverId;
                ChatId = chatId;
                Timestamp = timestamp;
                Content = content;
            }
    
            protected Message() { }
    
            public string MessageId { get; protected set; }
            public string FromId { get; protected set; }
            public string ChatId { get; protected set; }
            public string ReceiverId { get; protected set; }
            public long Timestamp { get; protected set; }
            public MessageContent Content { get; protected set; }
            //...métodos e afins
}
```

A propriedade **`MessageContent`** pode receber valores de diferentes tipos tais como `TextContent`, `ImageContent`, `DocumentContent` etc. Dessa forma, está sendo criadas classes que herdam de `Message` e atribuindo o tipo específico na propriedade genérica *Content* como no exemplo abaixo:

```
    public class ConversationMessage: Message
    {
        public ConversationMessage(..., TextContent textContent): base(...)
        {
            Content = textContent;
        }
    }
```

O meio apresentado acima é de fato "mais viável" para essa abordagem? Há um design melhor dessa simples abordagem?

Vi exemplos, onde também que pode ser feita a utilização de classes parciais (partial), onde `Message` seria uma classe parcial para conter propriedades de tipos filhos (tais como o `ConversationMessage`) e em seguida eliminá-los.

Comment: Poderia esclarecer um pouco mais. Eu não entendi o porque se é publico que você está fazendo *IoC* aqui `public MessageContent Content { get; protected set; }` porque teria que fazer uma especialização de *DI* num descendente em `ConversationMessage`?

Comment: Inicialmente, obrigado pelo comentário @AugustoVasques. Então, peço desculpas se fiz omissão de parte do código, na verdade o `MessageContent` é uma classe abstrata e `TextContent` herda de `MessageContent`. Esta é exatamente minha dúvida, pois sim, está funcionando, mas não sei se essa abordagem está totalmente correta.

Comment: Exercício por exercício(design pelo design) fica difícil de o responder, pois é algo de depende dos requisitos. Exemplo prático: Uma instituição financeira quer criar um novo produto cujo tenha um canal de troca de mensagens com cliente e administrador de carteiras de investimento, a interface do cliente fica ao seu cargo e de sua equipe, porém a interface com o administrador de investimento é legado. Então é uma situação que valida o seu design mas suponha que não haja esse requisito legado, me surge a pergunta porque há motivos para dois entry points para uma mesma atividade?